# Inject list of interfaces to a class - NestJs

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection, nestjs

Let's say I have this interface:

```
export interface IParser {
  parse(text: string):string
}
```

and a couple of classes implementing the interface:

```
@Injectable()
export class FirstParser implements IParser {
   public parse(text: string): string {
     return text + 'first';
   }
}

@Injectable()
export class SecondParser implements IParser {
   public parse(text: string): string {
     return text + 'second';
   }
}
```

Now, I have a service that I'm trying to inject to him list of parsers:

```
@Injectable()
export class ParserService {
    constructor(private readonly parsers: IParser[]) {}

    public parse(text: string): string {
        let parsedText = text;
        parsedText = this.parsers.reduce((acc: string, result) => {
            return result.parse(acc);
        }, parsedText);
        return parsedText;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to make the app module (in this case the parser-service.module.ts) to work
by injecting array/list of the class including FirstParser, SecondParser.

```
@Module({
    providers: [
        ParserService,
        {
          provide: Array<IParser>,
          useClass: ???,
        },
    ],
})
export class ParserServiceModule {}
```

Any ideas? is it possible at all in NestJs?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The functionality you are trying to achieve has already been requested as a feature but hasn't been implemented due to the low priority. Take a look at the [feature request](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/770).

However, you could utilize the `factory provider` functionality by turning the `IParser` implementations into an array.

```js
@Module({
    providers: [
        FirstParser,
        SecondParser,
        {
          provide: 'Parser',
          useFactory: (...parsers) => new ParserService(parsers),
          inject: [FirstParser, SecondParser],
        },
    ],
})
export class ParserServiceModule {}
```

Comment: So the module name is 'Parser' also when I'm using it in the test module.
```service = module.get< ParserService >('Parser');```

Comment: @yairabr correct, you access this custom provider by its token - `Parser`.